# Relative imports when deploying a python3 WSGI Flask application

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, wsgi

I am receiving the error `ImportError: No module named 'parse_data’` when I try to run `python wsgi.py`.

The application runs fine when I call it manually:

```
$/var/www/myapp# python src/app.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

The folder structure is as follows:

```
myapp
|-- src
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- app.py
|   |-- parse_data.py
|   |-- static
|   `-- templates
`-- wsgi.py
```

**Contents of wsgi.py**

```
import os
import sys

PROJECT_DIR = '/var/www/myapp'
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_DIR)

sys.path.append('/var/www/myapp/app')

def execfile(filename):
    globals = dict( __file__ = filename )
    exec( open(filename).read(), globals )

activate_this = os.path.join( PROJECT_DIR, 'pyenv/bin', 'activate_this.py' )
execfile( activate_this )

from src.app import app as application
```

**Contents of app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, url_for
import sys

import parse_data

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/dashboard")
def dashboard():
    data = parse_data.load_and_format_data()

    title = 'My application'

    return render_template('dashboard.html', data=data, heading=title, page_title=title)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I can't see what is wrong.  Changing `import parse_data` to `from src import parse_data` does make wsgi work, but then causes `python src/app.py` to break.

I have tried adding `sys.path.append('/var/www/myapp')` to the wsgi.py but this does not seem to have any effect.

The strange thing is that everything seems to work ok using python 2.7.

Comment: Any luck since then? I am interested in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are stuck, you can use the following:

```
from . import parse_data
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit this exact issue, very hard to search for!

I'm not sure how you're initializing your uWSGI instance, but that seems key here.

I have a slightly different folder structure than you. I have my imported modules in their own subfolders, like this:

```
myapp
|-- src
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- app.py
|   |-- parse_data
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- parse_data.py
|   |-- static
|   `-- templates
`-- wsgi.py
```

I was able to solve the issue by adding the location of my `app.py` to the "pythonpath" config in uWSGI.

I'm using a `uwsgi.ini` config file instead of a `wsgi.py`.  After the fix, my config file looks something like this:

```
chdir = /path/to/myapp
plugin = python
wsgi-file = ./src/app.py
callable = app

; Next line is the fix
pythonpath = ./src
```

In your case, I believe this means your `wsgi.py` needs an additional line:

```py
sys.path.append('/var/www/myapp/src')
```